# gitignore to allow obj models but not compiled obj files

Tags: c++, git, opengl, github

So I'm trying to figure out a suitable gitignore for an OpenGL project. I have the standard C++ gitignore.

Now it ignores .objs, for compiled object file, rightfully so.
However, it also ignores models that are of the .obj format and I do want tracked by version control.

How can I have setup the gitignore to ignore .objs, except from the Assets directory?

Answer (score 2):

If the models are .obj, you should be able to just use

```
*.objs
```

in your gitignore to ignore compiled object files, while not ignoring .obj files because they will not match that.

If you want to not ignore .objs that are inside of the Assets folder, you can do

```
# Ignore compiled files
*.objs

# Don't want to ignore .objs files in Assets
!Assets/*.objs
```

From gitignore documentation:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".